# random matrix with special order in matlab

Tags: random

this is my simple code: A=randi([0,1],[500,500])
this code gives me matrix A(500*500) that all elements are 0 or 1.

is it any way that I can order that the number of 1 in this element be 7000.

Is it possible to guide me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I don't think the randi function is the way to start here.

I would suggest the following procedure:

1. Start with a list with 500*500 elements, with 7000 elements set to `1` and the rest to `0`
2. Randomize the order of elements in the list
3. Make an 500*500 array whose elements are the elements of the list

For instance, the following code would work:

```
A_init(1:7000) = 1; A_init(7001:500*500) = 0  % step 1
A = A_init(randperm(length(A_init)))          % step 2
A = reshape(A,[500,500])                      % step 3
```

The key is the use of `randperm`, which generates a random permutation of the indices.

To verify that A has the correct number of elements:

```
num_ones = length(find(A==1))
```